# How to get provider authorities value from an Android manifest file programmatically in Xamarin Forms?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, android-manifest

I'm developing an Android app with Xamarin.Forms, and I'm using the AndroidManifest.xml file shown below.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
      android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0">
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="26" android:targetSdkVersion="26" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<application android:label="MyApp.Android">
    <provider
        android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
        android:authorities="myapp.fileprovider"
        android:exported="false"
        android:grantUriPermissions="true">
        <meta-data
          android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
          android:resource="@xml/provider_file_paths" />
    </provider>
</application>
```

I'd like to get the `android:authorities` value of the `provider` directive (in my case "myapp.fileprovider" as string) programmatically.
How is this possible with Xamarin.Forms?

Answer (score 3):

I found an answer.

```
var context = Android.App.Application.Context;
var component = new Android.Content.ComponentName(context, Java.Lang.Class.FromType(typeof(Android.Support.V4.Content.FileProvider)));
var info = context.PackageManager.GetProviderInfo(component, Android.Content.PM.PackageInfoFlags.MetaData);
var authority = info.Authority;
```

Kotlin version as a helper function

```kotlin
fun getFileProviderAuthorities(context: Context): String {
    val component = ComponentName(context, FileProvider::class.java)
    val info = context.packageManager.getProviderInfo(component, android.content.pm.PackageManager.GET_META_DATA)
    return info.authority
}
```